# Composer, autoloading & class calling after autoloading

Tags: php, composer-php, standards, psr-4

I was wondering, I am currently trying to change my programming style to work with composer and its package system (my god why didn't I use it sooner?) but I was wondering I am trying to work following the PSR-4 standard.

And got the following php file

```
<?php

require_once(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');

$class = new vendorname\packagename\classname;

$example = new vendorname\packagename\subpackage\classname2;
```

Is that good practice to use with composer and the PSR-4 standard?

Where the the classes are existing in:

```
- /vendor
-- /vendorname
--- /packagename
--- /src
---- classname.php
---- /subpackage
----- classname2.php
```

I am currently thinking it is, but I just want to make sure that I am using it correctly according to the PSR-4 standard :-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically that is the way to go, but some packages use different namespaces (mainly packages that need to have legacy support, for as far as I have encountered). Therefore after you `composer require` the package and it's installed, you should check the files for the namespaces that are used. But yes, you are right, because the way you say it is how it's typically done.

Also usually the package's readme/website has some examples on how to construct their objects.

Example: The [Monolog logger package](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog) has a file  /vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php that is in the `Monolog` namespace, not in the `Monolog\Monolog\Src\Monolog` namespace. Just be sure to check it, but most of the times examples on the package maintainer/owner's website will tell you how to use the package. In this example the readme on Github tells you how the package is used.

Comment: Yeah, well thats the wierd part indeed, I require other packages within my application though some times I only need to use `vendorname\classname` and other times it doenst make sense one bit on why the namespace is what it is...

Answer (score 0):

Most of packages include readme referring it's namespace. you can access classes using that namespace. if you can't found you can check from 'your_project_root/vendor/vendor_name/package_name/composer.json'.

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {"Monolog\\": "src/Monolog"}
    },
```

For this example 'Monolog' is the namespace and this is the best way to follow psr standards.

```
<?php

use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;

// create a log channel
$log = new Logger('name');
$log->pushHandler(new StreamHandler('path/to/your.log', Logger::WARNING));

// add records to the log
$log->warning('Foo');
$log->error('Bar');
```

You can see all this standards in https://www.php-fig.org/psr/

Additionally you can check how this packages loaded in 'autoload_psr4.php' located in

> 'your_project_root/vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php'

when you run `composer require, composer update or composer dump-autoload` command. this file will updated.